# React useParams: trouble with linking 'username' in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm creating a blog page in React and I'm having trouble dynamically changing the profiles in the route of my router for them to switch with useParams + useState. I've tried adding a function outside the App function, adding in a hook inside the function but I'm kinda stuck.

I know I'm missing something to link the 'username' to the profile but I'm not sure what it is.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
// App.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Buzzwords from "./sections/Buzzwords";
import Nats from "./sections/Nats";
import Profile from "./sections/Profile";
import Nav from "./sections/Nav";
import "./App.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

// function Profiles() {
//   const { username } = useParams();
//   return <h3>ID: {username}</h3>;
// }

function App() {
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState("");
  let { username } = useParams();
  // return <h3> profile of: {username}</h3>;
  // React.useEffect(() => {

  // }, [selectedUser]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <header className="App-header">
          Natter
          <Nav />
        </header>
        <main>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/buzzwords">
              <Buzzwords />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/nats">
              <Nats handleUserClick={setSelectedUser} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/profile/:username">
              <Profile username={selectedUser} />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;






// Profile.js

import React from "react";
import ProfileHeader from "../components/ProfileHeader";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const users = {
  roland: {
    username: "Roland",
    displayName: "R.S.",
  },
  tommy: {
    username: "Tommy",
    displayName: "T.B.",
  },
};

const Profile = ({ username }) => {
  if (!username) {
    return (
      <section className="profile">
        <h2>Profile</h2>
        <p>No user selected</p>
      </section>
    );
  }
  const user = users[username];
  // const { username } = useParams();

  // not sure if the link is needed based on the prop calling the user in ProfileHeader
  return (
    <section className="profile">
      <Link to={`/profile/${Profile.username}}`}> 
        <h2>Profile</h2>
        <ProfileHeader {...user}></ProfileHeader>
      </Link>
    </section>
  );
};

// const Profile = () => {
//   const { username }: { username: string } = useParams;
//   return <div>Stuff: {username}</div>;
// };

export default Profile;
```

Comment: where do you select the user?

Answer (score 0):

Error might be in `Link` tag of `Profile` component, refer following code

```js
return (
  <section className="profile">
    // here you have added extra '}' after Profile.username so that might be the issue
    <Link to={`/profile/${Profile.username}`}> 
      <h2>Profile</h2>
      <ProfileHeader {...user}></ProfileHeader>
    </Link>
  </section>
);
```